# Move UIImageview with Touches Moved when pressing anywhere in UIView IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I have a `UIView` and `UIImageView` inside the `UIView`. I use Touches method to drag the `UIImageView`.

This works great. I have one problem though.

I want the `UIImageView` to drag or move when I touch on anywhere in the UIView. Currently this the UIImageview can only move when the UIIMageView is touched and not the UIView.

```
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 135, 300, 200)];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// Create an instance of the image to drag
ImageToDrag *img2 = [[ImageToDrag alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"markit_btn.png"]];
img2.center = CGPointMake(110, 75);
img2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[subview addSubview:img2];
[self.view  addSubview:subview];
```

I have a separate file which I include in header file of the Controller that the UIView sits in.

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
if (self = [super initWithImage:image])
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
return self;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
// When a touch starts, get the current location in the view
currentPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
// Get active location upon move
CGPoint activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

// Determine new point based on where the touch is now located
CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x + (activePoint.x - currentPoint.x),
                             self.center.y + (activePoint.y - currentPoint.y));

//--------------------------------------------------------
// Make sure we stay within the bounds of the parent view
//--------------------------------------------------------
float midPointX = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds);
// If too far right...
 if (newPoint.x > self.superview.bounds.size.width  - midPointX)
  newPoint.x = self.superview.bounds.size.width - midPointX;
else if (newPoint.x < midPointX)     // If too far left...
  newPoint.x = midPointX;

float midPointY = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds);
// If too far down...
if (newPoint.y > self.superview.bounds.size.height  - midPointY)
  newPoint.y = self.superview.bounds.size.height - midPointY;
else if (newPoint.y < midPointY)    // If too far up...
  newPoint.y = midPointY;

// Set new center location
self.center = newPoint;
}
```

Regards

Comment: where do you override touchesBegan, touchesMoved ..., in UIView class or in UIIamgeView class ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry this is suuuper late but just in case anyones else needs help with this alteration, check out this code:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: touch.view];
"YOURVIEW".center = touchLocation;
```

Basically, you have to set the event to occur anywhere on the view.

I hope this helps someone out there ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to make your `UIView *subview` a custom class with the `touchesBegan:` and so on overridden.  Then you need to make your UIImageView `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO`.  That way any touch event on your custom `UIView` will be controlled by the view and you can do whatever you please with it or it's subviews (the `UIImageView`).

Your `UIView` subclass will have to contain your `UIImageView` in it's class variables in order to manipulate it during the touch events, but that's easy enough to figure out.